# Calculating distances from points to centre of cells using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, distance, attribute-table

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 (using older version because I need the Qmarxan plugin which is not available for 2.4.0).  I have a study area that has a vector laying of "planning units", or cells over the top (several thousand cells). Each planning unit has an individual ID and a couple of other fields in the attribute table. I then have a vector point layer with 8 points (ranger stations).

I need to calculate the distances from the centre of every cell to the nearest point, and have this as a new column in the attribute table.  Later, I will need to do the same calculation but from the centre of each cell to the nearest road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can achieve this by using the **Distance to nearest hub** function via *Processing Toolbox*. Select the required options (first image), and choose what measurement you want the distance to be calculated in which will be added into a new column. You can repeat this step to then calculate the centre of each cell to the nearest road (second image).

Hope this helps!

[image: Distance to nearest hub]

[image: Distance to nearest hub analysis]

Comment: Thanks Joseph - that worked perfectly for calculating the distance from the centre of each cell to the ranger stations.  I tried it with the roads however, and its not working as well (the lines are being drawn to areas with no road!)  But I think that is a problem with my shapefiles, not the method. If I figure out what going wrong I'll leave another comment

Comment: Glad something worked! You could try using _Vector_ > _Geometry Tools_ > _Check geometry validity_. This may help show you if there are errors somewhere.